# Embed external blog page into website without PHP

Tags: html, blogs, github-pages

I'm looking to open up a blog on my website which is hosted with github pages so there is no room for PHP (unfortunately!).

I was wondering if I anyone knows of a blogging platform (blogger, tumblr don't seem to do such things) in which I could have a live blog feed on my website from an external blog I set up.

Looked around with the Goog and haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe, or you might be able to use some AJAX in combination with a blogging API (such as [blogger's](https://developers.google.com/blogger/)).

Many modern blogging platforms have a RESTful API to access blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages [supports Jekyll](https://github.com/blog/1867-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0), which actually is a blogging platform. Have you tried setting up Jekyll and using the built in blog?

Jekyll is built on [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki) which has support for logic, partials, variables, etc. See the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/) for more info.

Also, you can see my personal [blog site](http://joelglovier.com) for an example blog site (and [corresponding GitHub repo](https://github.com/jglovier/jglovier.github.io)).